# Xamarin mac app got crashed & closing window

Tags: xamarin.mac

App got crashed when i try to pick item from collection view,can anyone help me with this crash log? i need to locate inside my source where is the problem!?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows a "notify observers" call, so my guess is that you have a KVO bindings that you are not deregistering from or keeping the target alive to be called.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html